# How to calculate values from input type="text" and select element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, select

How do I calculate fields in a form with both input type and select element with jQuery?

For example

```
<input class="days" type="text" name="txt"/>
<select class="roomtype">
<option value="">Please select a room</option>
<option value="50">Budget room</option>
<option value="100">Standard room</option>
</select>
<p>Please bank in <a href="bankurl" id="total">$</a> to our account.
```

The script that I have currently ask the users to enter their price.

```
$(".days").each(function() { 
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            Calculate();
        });
    });

});

function Calculate() {

    var total = 0;

    $(".days").each(function() {
         // validate
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
       }
     });
    //decimal
    $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
$(".days").each(function() { 
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        Calculate();
    });
});

function Calculate() {

    var total = 0;

    $(".days").each(function() {
         // validate
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
       }
     });
    //decimal
    var cost = total.toFixed(2) * $(".roomtype").val();
    cost += "$";
    $("#total").html(cost);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wALQT/

Answer (score 0):

You can get `select`'s value using `$('.roomtype').val()`.

Comment: Thank you. I should really sit down with a jQuery book.